# Gulp Error Message "File not found" on MacOS

Tags: bash, macos, npm, gulp

I'm attempting to get Gulp up and running on MacOS 10.12.3. However, no matter what I do, I am getting the following error: No Gulp File Found.

I have done the following:

1. Installed gulp cli globally via sudo bash. Gulp version as of this writing is 3.9.1
2. Installed gulp locally via npm install gulp. Gulp version as of this writing is 3.9.1.
3. I've done the touch gulp command. This has created a 0kb blank gulp file.

   4. [I've created a test gulp.js file in my root directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fj7kE.png). The code for said file looks like`var gulp = require('gulp');`

Any thoughts on what's going on here?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `gulp` file needs to be called `gulpfile.js`, not `gulp.js`.

---

While you're at it, I also recommend initializing `npm` by running `npm init` (it will walk you through it… just use all the defaults for now), and then adding `gulp` to your `package.json` by running `npm install --save gulp`. This will add

```
"dependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.1"
}
```

to your `package.json`.

What's the point of this? `npm`'s `package.json`'s `"dependencies"` becomes a list of all the gulp-related plugins your project needs. Any time you need to recreate the project, all you need is that `package.json` and you can run `npm install` to install them.

---

Note that even after renaming your file, you'll get the error

```
Task 'default' is not in your gulpfile
```

At the very least `gulpfile.js` will have to include the line `gulp.task('default');`… but if that's all your `gulpfile` has, you won't actually be *doing* anything with `gulp`.

I highly recommend working through css-trick's [Gulp for Beginners](https://css-tricks.com/gulp-for-beginners/) - it doesn't take long, and you'll come out with a much more complete understanding of how to use `gulp`.